# Haproxy 4 frontend servers

Tags: networking, server, web-applications, load-balancing, haproxy

In my company i have 20 web servers and use 4 haproxy servers to load balance the requests, i have configured them separately by declaring all 20 web apps ip in 4 haproxy and they are working pretty well. I have declared each ip of haproxy in dns with diferent name like web1, web2, web3, web4.
All i need is if there is any way to make these haproxy comunicate with each other and get information about other haproxy requests so if a client get loged in the webapp1 from web1 the other client dont get loged in on the same webapp from web2 becouse i think sometimes from monitoring haproxy there are more sesions on the same backend servers which may come from not getting infromation beetwen haproxy servers.

I have tried to declare other haproxy in the frontend section but i think there is a crash

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you take a look into the stick table feature of HAProxy.
There is a quite good explanation in this blog post [Introduction to HAProxy Stick Tables](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/introduction-to-haproxy-stick-tables/)